# User input is overly accepting

Tags: botframework, chatbot, bot-framework-composer, azure-language-understanding

When following along the tutorial at [Tutorial: Add LUIS for language understanding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/tutorial/tutorial-luis?tabs=v2x) it walks me through setting up a weather bot. One of the final steps is to set up input in the format of

```
- get weather
- weather
- how is the weather

> Define a postal code entity. Any time LUIS sees a five digit number, it will flag it as 'postal code' entity.
$ postalcode:/[0-9]{5}/
```

This works very well and if I test it using "hi" then it goes into the unknown intent trigger and "weather" falls into the getWeather dialog. Attempting to setup my own bot using different phrases is not having the same results. If I take the exact same bot I made in the tutorial and replace it's phrases with

```
- orphaned lock
- locked
- lock
```

Then testing with "hi" goes into the getWeather dialog (same as if I had said "weather" with the original input phrases).

I get this same overly permissive behavior in a new project or as above where I just edit the trigger phrases. It seems to only work as expected with the original phrases from the tutorial.

What am I doing wrong that is causing the overly permissive behavior? I would expect using "hi" when my phrases are one of the "locked" ones to fall into the unknown intent trigger.

Comment: Can you share the code where your bot is initiating the intent based on the LUIS result? It's hard to know exactly what is going wrong without seeing the code.

Comment: If you run your bot in Emulator you should be able to see how LUIS is scoring your utterances, which may help with debugging as well.